# Execution failed for task ':telephony:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: flutter

e: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\telephony-0.1.4\android\src\main\kotlin\com\shounakmulay\telephony\sms\SmsMethodCallHandler.kt: (49, 1): Class 'SmsMethodCallHandler' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onRequestPermissionsResult(p0: Int, p1: Array<(out) String!>, p2: IntArray): Boolean defined in io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.RequestPermissionsResultListener
e: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\telephony-0.1.4\android\src\main\kotlin\com\shounakmulay\telephony\sms\SmsMethodCallHandler.kt: (357, 3): 'onRequestPermissionsResult' overrides nothing
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':telephony:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED IT!

It was a null safety issue, I just updated the dependency to the latest version
from telephony: ^0.1.2 to telephony: ^0.2.0